# Is it possible to create a custom pagelayout in a wikilibrary?

Tags: wiki

I have created a publish site collection. I created a wiki library. Is it possible to create my custom pagelayout for this wiki library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. The steps are:

- Go to Design Manager on your site and select Edit Page Layouts > Create a Page Layout
- Choose Enterprise Wiki Page as the content type
- Edit the HTML file that is created to create the layout of your liking, then publish it
- Use your new layout when creating a new page

Full step by step can be found [here](http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/111/Create-custom-wiki-page-layout-in-SharePoint-2013).

Comment: I do not see the contenttype Enterprise Wiki Page. Do I mis some feature? It is not a wiki site. It is a publishing site collection.

Comment: Are you running SharePoint Foundation or Enterprise?

Comment: I can see the contenttype now. When I click on create new page. It is using the custom wiki pagelayout, but the wrong library "Pages". I would like to use the wiki library. Is this possible?

Comment: To create the page you need to go to your wiki library > click the settings cog icon in the top right of the page > click Add Page. This page will get added into your wiki library.